# Flask-security create role,user and linking user_id to role_id

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-security

I  using Flask-Security with SQLAlchemy

When want to add user or role

```
def addrole():
        form=addroll()
        createRole=user_datastore.create_role(name=form.role.data,description=form.description.data)
        db.session.add(createRole)
        db.session.commit()
```

in mysql table add one record belong my creation and two or tree blank record same think happen when i want to create user
To associate a user with a role, I have the following :

```
   @app.route('/addR', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
   @login_required
   def addR():
      email1=request.form['emails']
      role1=request.form['role2']
      user = user_datastore.find_user(email=request.args.get('email1'))
      role = user_datastore.find_role(request.args.get('role1'))
      user_datastore.add_role_to_user(user, role)
      db.session.commit()
      return  redirect('/addroletouser' )
```

It  linking a wrong user_id and role_id in roles_users table.

Answer (score 4):

When using Flask-Security with SQLAlchemy you do not need to manually link the records, you can use `create_role` and `create_user` from the `user_datastore`.
This is the same `user_datastore` that you used to initialise Flask-Security.
A simple example (do not use plain text password please):

```
def seed():
  user_datastore.create_role(name='admin')
  user_datastore.create_user(username='admin', email='admin@example.com',
                             password='admin', roles=['admin'])
```

Comment: When I seed the data, I added the code like above. but since we don't add any custom code for registration, how does create_role gets triggered? how do I make it add role on registration ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The helpers come with the Flask-Security extension. This is a seed method, you call it on startup. You should create your roles when seeding. Then add a default role for regular users when you create them, and you'll need somewhat custom forms (depends on your app architecture). I use it conjunction with Flask-Admin and WTForms and it may be a good starting point for you.

Comment: @JPro Use a .click command to be able to insert some admin users on production database.